# What adjectives are used to describe a successful meeting?

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I want to express my wish for a good meeting with a successful outcome.

For example:

> I hope the meeting is ____________ and has a successful outcome."

What adjective(s) would work well in the blank to express the hope for a good meeting?

Answer (score 2):

Your adjectives and nouns are fine in my opinion, but your grammar makes it hard to be....er...well...effective

I'd say "Let's hope we are going to have an effective meeting with really successful outcomes"

I think it would be good to start in this way.......

Comment: I can't imagine myself saying "Let's hope we have .. really successful outcomes" at the start of a meeting.